# How to add key values pair in object in JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

how can I push keys and values in an empty object?

You are provided with an array, possibleIterable. Using a for loop, build out the object divByThree so that each key is an element of possibleIterable that is divisible by three. The value of each key should be the array index at which that key can be found in possibleIterable.

```
const possibleIterable = [4, 3, 9, 6, 23];
const divByThree = {};
// ADD CODE HERE
for (let i =0 ; i < possibleIterable.length; i++)
  {
    if (possibleIterable[i] % 3 === 0)
   {
      // ADD CODE HERE!
         
      }
  }
console.log(divByThree)
```

Comment: you can't push value in object. Object contains only single value (key value pair)  at a time. (it can have different key value pairs.)

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot *push* on to an object. You have to specify the key and value like so:

**Literally**

```
divByThree.key = value
```

Note, in the above example, key is the literal key name, and so you would access it like:

```
divByThree.key
divByThree['key']  // note the quotes around key
```

**Dynamically**

If you want to create a dynamic key based on a js variable for example, you can do:

```
const keyName = 'myKey';
divByThree[keyName] = value;
```

To access the value, you can do:

```
divByThree[keyName];  // no quotes. Value of keyName variable
divByThree['myKey'];
divByThree.myKey;
```

Comment: I Tried that. But I have to add multiple keys and values according to my condition.By doing this divByThree.key = value. I think it replaces the key and values every time the loop iterates. I have to keep adding like append

Comment: well then you have to do the above multiple times for the number of keys/values you need. It may be worth updating your question to be more specific.

Comment: If you have a key which already exists in the object then it will overwrite it. Your keys have to be unique

Comment: Oh. Got it. Thank you

Comment: No probs. If that has solved your issue then upvote and accept the answer please

Answer (score 2):

```
divByThree.key = value
```

or

```
divByThree['key'] = value
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (let i = 0; i < possibleIterable.length; i++) {
  if (possibleIterable[i] % 3 === 0) {
    divByThree[possibleIterable[i]] = i;
  }
}
```

This is probably what you were looking for. This assigns new key-value pairs, where the key is an element in `possibleIterable` that is divisible by 3 and the value is the index position of that element.

So if you `console.log(divByThree)`, it should print out

> ```
> { 3: 1, 6: 3, 9: 2 }
> ```

I understand that this is an old post, but thought I should give an answer for anyone looking in the future.